# creating task in opportunity when stage change occurs using process builder

Tags: process-builder

as i am new to salesforce could you guide me on following.

when the opportunity stage changes, task should create using process builder.
i did with entry criteria is opportunity.stagename ischanges is true then create new record whith required fileds.
but task is not creating for the opportunity.

Anybody can you help me in this.thanks
[image: here is the screen shot]

Comment: can you add pictures of your process builder configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add following in Set Field Values section,

> `Related to ID` reference [Opportunity].Id,

then only task will be getting created under Opportunity.